# How do a fix this solid, leaning, solid concrete retaining wall

Tags: concrete, drainage, retaining-wall, digging

I have a solid concrete retaining wall that’s leaning against my neighbor’s property. In turn, he has let his yard foliage grow to hedge against it collapsing, which is why it’s hard to get clear photos.

Since it’s a solid hunk of concrete and not blocks, I’m not sure how I can fix it, if not push it back. Would digging behind it and getting enough people to push it back work? That seems too easy, but I'd like to know.

The reasons it’s leaning is probably because I had a giant tree in my front yard and have poor drainage all around the property.

[image: retaining wall leaning away from a structure]

[image: Top down view of the wall and ground]

[image: peeking at the wall through the trees]

[image: Wider view of the peek through the trees]

Comment: If you think digging behind it and pushing it back is "too easy" you're a better man than I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience it's nearly impossible to push such a concrete wall back to its original position.

The best approach is to break it up and remove it and then if you want a wall there, replace it with one that has proper drainage so that it won't get pushed over again.

Comment: I think this is what I’ll do. Gonna get a pro for the demo and do the rebuild myself

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with jwh20's answer, only differ in "it is possible but not cheap". You can hire a geotechnical engineer, who is familiar with "underpinning technics" and solving groundwater issues.